# XQuery [value()]: A string literal was expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to execute this code:

```
if exists(select * from FileUploadFileTable..sysobjects where  xtype='u' and name='##Tmp830963'  )
        drop table  ##Tmp830963
        CREATE table  ##Tmp830963 (RowId int,Files varchar(MAX) ,Files_Name NVARCHAR(MAX), Files_Size bigint,Job_Id  bigint, Files_Type VARCHAR(MAX) , User_id bigint  ,User_Name  NVARCHAR(MAX)) Insert into ##Tmp830963(RowId,Files,Files_Name,Files_Size  , Files_Type)  select A.row_num,A.Items,O.Items,B.Items,C.Items
         from(
        SELECT Items,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num
        FROM  dbo.Func_Split('/9j/AqAAAAB4CgAwAEAAABAAAAAAA', '^') ) A
        join
        (SELECT Items,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num
        FROM  dbo.Func_Split('tt^', '^') ) O  on  O.row_num=A.row_num 
         join
        (SELECT Items,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num
        FROM  dbo.Func_Split('12^', '^'))B       on  A.row_num=B.row_num 
         join
         (SELECT Items,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num
         FROM  dbo.Func_Split('png^', '^'))C
         on   C.row_num=A.row_num 
        update  ##Tmp830963 set User_Name=100update  ##Tmp830963 set Job_Id='20' update  ##Tmp830963 set User_id='1' select * from  ##Tmp830963  DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (ID uniqueidentifier)    INSERT INTO [Uploads]  ([file_stream],[name])  OUTPUT INSERTED.stream_id INTO @OutputTbl(ID)  select cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable(Files))', 'varbinary(max)') ,Files_Name   from ##Tmp830963 while (select count(*)  from @OutputTbl) > 0 begin INSERT INTO [dbo].[FileDescriptions]  ([User_ID] ,[FileName],Stream_id,[Size],Job_Id)   select   [User_id] ,cast((select MAX(ID) from @OutputTbl   )  as nvarchar(max) ),(select MAX(ID) from @OutputTbl) , Files_Size  ,  Job_Id   from ##Tmp830963  where RowId=(select top 1(RowId) from ##Tmp830963)  delete @OutputTbl  where ID =(select MAX(ID) from @OutputTbl )  end
```

But I get this error:

> XQuery [value()]: A string literal was expected

On this line:

> ```
> cast(N'''' as xml).value(''xs:base64Binary(sql:variable(Files))''
> ```

Comment: What is the data type of @TempTable? To use a variable for a table name in dynamic SQL it should be type SYSNAME.

Comment: There are far bigger problems you have right now; that SQL is an injection nightmare. You need to be quoting your object names (`QUOTENAME` is very useful) and parametrising your statement, not injecting them (`sp_executesql` supports parametrised queries). After that use `PRINT @SQL;` or `SELECT @SQL;` to inspect the value of your dynamic SQL, debug that, and then debug your SQL that generates the statement. i'm afraid we can't help you much more than that; we can't run that SQL, or inspect the value of `@Sql`.

Comment: What are you trying to obtain from an empty xml?

Comment: @LuisCazares, the *empty XML* is a trick to allow for the native XML-type methods without really having a XML. This trick is used to translate `base64` to `varbinary`. Some examples: 1) formula computation: `SELECT CAST('' AS XML).value('((3.0+4.2)*.5) div 3.5','real')` or 2) `TRY_CAST` in versions before v2012: `DECLARE @s VARCHAR(10)='blah'; /*use a number instead*/
SELECT CAST('' AS XML).value('sql:variable("@s") cast as xs:int?','int')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first sight this looks a bit weird. I'm pretty sure, that this can be solved differently.

You are trying to transfer `base64` to `varbinary`, correct?
Well, the XML-approach is the recommended way to achieve this. However, your problem seems to be situated here:

```
cast(N'''' as xml).value(''xs:base64Binary(sql:variable(Files))''
```

This is your attempt to create the needed statement dynamically, hence the doubled single quotes. This will translate to

```
cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable(Files))'
```

The problem here is: `sql:variable()` expects the name of a declared variable as a string literal. Furthermore, `value()` expects two arguments: The `Xpath` and the data type. You'd need something like this

```
cast(N'' as xml).value('sql:variable("@Files")','varbinary(max)')
```

Might be you need `sql:column("SomeColumn")`, which allows to use the value of a column.

### One example to demonstrate this

```
--We use FOR XML to get the binary 0x1234 as base64
SELECT 0x1234 FOR XML PATH(''); --returns "EjQ="

--Now I place the corresponding base64 string in a string variable 
DECLARE @base64 VARCHAR(100)='EjQ=';

--And this is, how XML is returning the binary 0x1234 from the base64-string
SELECT CAST('' AS XML).value('sql:variable("@base64")','varbinary(max)');
```

And this would return the same and looks a bit easier:

```
SELECT CAST(@base64 AS XML).value('.','varbinary(max)');
```

### Check this for a tabular approach

The table `@base64` is a declared table variable, just use your original table instead:

```
--Declare a table variable with one string column and insert the base64 of 0x1234
DECLARE @base64 TABLE(Files VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @base64 VALUES('EjQ=');

--use the same trick as above to get the varbinary back
SELECT CAST(Files AS XML).value('.','varbinary(max)')
FROM @base64;
```

Comment: thanks I want use Files ..Files is Column database .Files is not declare is field databse.

Comment: thanks cast(N'''' as xml).value(''xs:base64Binary(sql:column("Files")) but see error  A file entry cannot have a NULL value for the data stream associated with the row. Insert file data or use 0x to insert a zero length file